# Differences between type definions and their meanings in typeid(equalizing)

Tags: c++, c, types, typeid

`unsigned int` = `unsigned`

`int` = `signed int` = `signed`

`signed long long int` = `singed long long` = `long long`

`unsigned long long int` = `unsigned long long`

`signed long int` = `signed long` = `long`

`unsigned long int` = `unsigned long`

`signed short int` = `signed short` = `short`

`unsigned short int` = `unsigned short`

`signed char` = `char`

I'm wondering are the types i mentioned above same in C or C++ ?
If it is, wondering their meanings while equalizing each other, would they be same again ? (EX: `typeid(signed long int)` == `typeid(long)`)

Answer: http://cpp.sh/3rm

Comment: There is no `typeid` in C. Also in C, `unsigned int` is definitely not the same type as `signed int`, and `signed char` does not have to be the same type as `char`, so what is your question again?

Comment: The question if the types are different in C still applies. `typeid` is just the runtime manifestation of a type identification. A question which is clearly stated in the question body, btw, no need to close vote for "unclear what you're asking"...

Comment: Related: [Are signed, unsigned, long and short all valid types in all versions of C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493879/are-signed-unsigned-long-and-short-all-valid-types-in-all-versions-of-c-and-c)

Comment: I'm not comparing unsigned and signed. They are absolutely not the same. It seems i forgot to add some new lines, sorry for confusion. By the way, I asked typeid for C++ of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some types are the same, some are distinct (=not the same):

- for `char`, adding `signed` and `unsigned` gives you three distinct types in total.
- for `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long`, `signed` is implied, and adding that does nothing. Adding `unsigned` will give you a new set of distinct types.
- `unsigned`, `short`, `long`, and `long long` can be followed by `int`, but if the `int` is there or not does not give distinct types.

In principle, the `typeid` of all the distinct types should be different. What this means is that template and function overload resolution will view these as different types, whereas e.g. passing a `short` and `short int` will both call the same overload.

As far as I'm aware, these rules are the same for C and C++. If I made a mistake, please tell me, I'm writing this off the top of my head.

To check this, you can use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) combined with [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) for a compile-time check:

```
#include <type_traits>
using std::is_same;

static_assert(!is_same<char, signed char>(), "");
static_assert(!is_same<char, unsigned char>(), "");
static_assert(!is_same<unsigned char, signed char>(), "");


static_assert( is_same<short, signed short>(), "");
static_assert( is_same<int, signed int>(), "");
static_assert( is_same<long, signed long>(), "");
static_assert( is_same<long long, signed long long>(), "");

static_assert(!is_same<short, unsigned short>(), "");
static_assert(!is_same<int, unsigned int>(), "");
static_assert(!is_same<long, unsigned long>(), "");
static_assert(!is_same<long long, unsigned long long>(), "");

static_assert( is_same<unsigned int, unsigned>(), "");
static_assert( is_same<short int, short>(), "");
static_assert( is_same<long int, long>(), "");
static_assert( is_same<long long int, long long>(), "");

int main(){} // only included to make the program link
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5777c640853a66e3).

Comment: There are errors like "error C2057: expected constant expression". Anyway thanks for clarifying this.

Here it is a comparision: http://cpp.sh/3rm